# where can I get these kind of exercises to solve?

Tags: java

Recently I did a Java programming exercise successfully which was sent by a recruiting firm, The problem statement goes like this 'There are two text files FI(records abt files and directory information)  and FS(containing blocks of data) which represent a file Index and file System respectively and I was supposed to write a static read method in a class which will read the file  from the FS depending upon the path string provided using FI'  My question is where can I get these kind of exercises to solve, the complexity should be above average to tough.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Start here:

- [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/)
- [Programming Praxis](http://programmingpraxis.com/)
- [CodeKata](http://codekata.pragprog.com/)

**Warning!** These can become addictive causing you to anger a spouse and/or boss by spending too much time doing "just one more." (I'm guilty of angering both.)

Answer (score 3):

- http://www.facebook.com/careers/puzzles.php
- http://www.itasoftware.com/careers/hiringpuzzles.html
- Search GlassDoor interviews section for any major software engineering company (Google is a good one)

Answer (score 3):

This site has a lot of programming puzzles:

http://uva.onlinejudge.org/

I know they're not the kind that appear in interviews, but maybe you're interested as well.

Answer (score 1):

[CareerCup](http://www.careercup.com/page?pid=java-interview-questions) has questions actually asked by many interviwers.
Also found http://www.cafeaulait.org/books/jdr/exercises/ and [Coding Bat](http://codingbat.com/)